# Rightmove API and scraping technical and legal

Tags: api, screen-scraping

I'm looking to build an app using property data. Nestoria has a free API and rules of use and Zoopla an API you register for. OnTheMarket and Rightmove have same terms of use to the letter (bizarre for competitors?). Rightmove advertise an API for upload but not download - I can't find anything for OnTheMarket.

I've discovered that Rightmove does have an API although the post code search is obfuscated by their own outcode mappings...

https://api.rightmove.co.uk/api/sale/find?index=0&sortType=1&numberOfPropertiesRequested=2&locationIdentifier=OUTCODE%5E1&apiApplication=IPAD

I'm wary of using an API that's not promoted. The alternative is scraping, which is harder technically and legally questionable, although from what I read the data is in the public domain and so free to use.

I've contacted Rightmove but got no response.

Is anyone using the Rightmove api and had this authorised by them? Seems most strange that it's open and available but barely mentioned when searching for it.

Can anyone clarify what rules/law/ethics are in place for scraping data?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Am in the same boat, looking for property feeds. Did something become of your investigation?

Comment: For anyone that possibly tried the "api link" from above - I can see a parameter 'displayPropertyType' that accepts general filters like 'houses' or 'flats'. Is there a way to try and see more detailed results, like detached houses? I'm interested to see if the data actually matches the website

Comment: Why is webscraping "legally questionable"? A website publishes public information. All webscraping is is using that already public data in an automated way. There's nothing illegal about that.

Answer (score 14):

Don't query their hidden API. But you can run a web crawler on RightMove.co.uk website, and it is perfectly legal as outlined in their [Terms of Service](http://www.rightmove.co.uk/this-site/terms-of-use-and-privacy-policy.html) under section 3.3 :

> You must not use or attempt to use any automated program **unless the automated program identifies itself uniquely in the User Agent field** and is fully compliant with the Robots Exclusion Protocol

A web crawler like Apache Nutch perfectly follows the Robots Exclusion Protocol. From [their robots.txt file](http://rightmove.co.uk/robots.txt) I found they have elaborate nested sitemap.xml files, and hence **they rather promote organized but polite crawling** of their website. I was myself wanting to get their data, so I am beginning with my endeavour to crawl them with my resources - do let me know if you need access to this data.

Comment: I am interested in that. Can you please share with me your findings?

Comment: This has been changed now: "5.3
You must not use or attempt to use any automated program (including, without limitation, any spider or other web crawler) to access our system or this Site,or to fill in and/or send forms on our Site, or to search, display or obtain links to any part of this Site,..."

Comment: A web scraper has been built for Rightmove, see here: https://github.com/toby-p/rightmove_webscraper.py - the bottom of the readme states it's against T&Cs but for personal use, there can't be much difference in the number of requests being sent to Rightmove's servers using the scraper vs actually viewing their site as a typical user..

Comment: A good read on the topic: https://blog.apify.com/is-web-scraping-legal/#terms-of-use-and-scraping

Comment: THIS IS NO LONGER A GOOD ANSWER!  Their current T's and C's say "You must **not** use or attempt to use any automated program (including, without limitation, any spider or other web crawler) to access our system or this Site. You must not use any scraping technology on the Site"

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to scrape their data, here what their terms&conditions say about it:

"You must not use or attempt to use any automated program (including, without limitation, any spider or other web crawler) to access our system or this Site. You must not use any scraping technology on the Site. Any such use or attempted use of an automated program shall be a misuse of our system and this Site. Obtaining access to any part of our system or this Site by means of any such automated programs is strictly unauthorised."

Comment: I don’t believe users of websites are legally bound by T&C

Comment: Also you can only break TOCs if you have agreed to them.

Comment: Also, this term would exclude Google or any other search engine crawling their website, which I doubt is their intention.

Comment: the cease and desist would be a nightmare and would not go through the courts. this is not a discussion for SO

Comment: @jack thats not entirely true, by using there website in any manner you have already patially excepted their t&c's.. its like using a paid carpark, by parking there you have agreed to a certain set of conditions but i agree with jim-smith this would be better suited to law stack exchange and maybe link back to this question..

Comment: https://blog.apify.com/is-web-scraping-legal/

Comment: Thanks @FailingCoder, this is a good read. Particularly relevant to this topic is the section: https://blog.apify.com/is-web-scraping-legal/#terms-of-use-and-scraping